# How to pass variables dynamically in sed command

Tags: bash, shell

I want pass variable in sed command

```
sed '/CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE $variable RESETLOGS  ARCHIVELOG/d' sqls.sql
```

instead of variable, I want to replace variable = "TEST"

Final:

```
sed '/CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "TEST" RESETLOGS  ARCHIVELOG/d' sqls.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use double quotes. Strings wrapped with single quotes aren't parsed by bash.

```
#! /bin/bash
VAR=A
echo "$VAR" # will output A
echo '$VAR' # will output $VAR
```